# Need image, text, youtube, etc. jquery modal overlay with long description

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am looking for a jquery modal window script for displaying images, text, html, videos, etc.

There are a lot of great ones out there, but I am looking for one that allows for a long description (that isn't pulled from the title) - like highslide that lets you have a caption and will display the photo text to the right or left of your image in the same modal window.

Due to licensing, I can't use highslide. So I'm looking for something else.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of SimpleModal, http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: Both great suggestions. I'm hoping for something a little easier to use, as I am developing a theme and want the users to be able to delve right in. 

Does anyone know of a lightbox that uses longdesc?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [**BlockUI**](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) because in addition to customizable content and various ways to invoke and disimiss the overlay (even via timer), it allows you to block only a certain area of the page (i.e. target a specific div), or the whole page.